# Looping through a JSON array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have my json array with is this :

```
[{"id":"1","cid":"1","da":"08:00:00","a":"12:00:00","data":"2011-07-03","persone":"3","nome":"Via Bligny"},

{"id":"8","cid":"1","da":"08:30:00","a":"14:45:00","data":"2011-09-26","persone":"2","nome":"Via Bligny"},

{"id":"9","cid":"1","da":"08:30:00","a":"14:15:00","data":"2011-09-26","persone":"2","nome":"Via Bligny"}]
```

And i want to print it in a table, for example,

```
<tr><td>{id}</td><td>{da}</td><td>{a}</td><td>{data}</td>(ecc)</tr>
```

a row for each data set, but, if i try with this code

```
function ore(cid){
        $.post('index.php?act=ore', {cid : 1}, function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i){
                document.write(data[i].id);
            });
        });
    }
```

for example, this is the output

```
undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your code as shown will work [Here's proof](http://jsfiddle.net/4gpHT/). Have you verified that `data` is giving you what you expect?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're not parsing the JSON first. [See my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8871612/1106925).

Comment: Iesm i didn't parse the JSON :) i was used to use getJSON so i didn't do it ):

Comment: Just a thought - mixing jQuery with `document.write` doesn't look like you know what you're doing. If this function gets called after the document is loaded it will destroy the page. You should use jQuery's `.append` or any other manipulation method

Comment: I know, to was just for testing ;) don't worry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Your code as shown works fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/4gpHT/)

Because of this, I'm assuming that you haven't parsed the *JSON* into *JavaScript* before looping.

```
var parsed = $.parseJSON( data );
```

So your code would be...

```
function ore(cid){
    $.post('index.php?act=ore', {cid : 1}, function(data){

           // parse it first
        var parsed = $.parseJSON( data );

        $.each(parsed, function(i,v){
            document.write(parsed[i].id);
     //     document.write(v); // or like this
        });
    });
}
```

Without parsing, you're just looping over the characters in the string, and none of them will have an `id` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ore(cid){
        $.post('index.php?act=ore', {cid : 1}, function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                document.write(value.id);
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ore(cid){
    $.postJSON('index.php?act=ore', {cid : 1}, function(data){
        for(var i in data) {
            document.write(data[i].id);
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: i think i prefer parse the json;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function ore(cid){
        $.post('index.php?act=ore', {cid : 1}, function(data){

var arr = $.parseJSON( data );

for(x in arr){

    alert(arr[x]['id']);
    alert(arr[x]['da']);
    alert(arr[x]['a']);
    alert(arr[x]['data']);
    alert(arr[x]['ecc']);
}

    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you ;) had to parse the json

Answer (score 0):

You could and probably **should** use a templating system. You could use [the one jQuery provides](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/) :

```
$.template("tableRowTemplate",'<tr><td>${id}</td><td>${da}</td><td>${a}</td><td>${data}</td>${ecc}</tr>');
function ore(cid){
    var result;
    $.post('index.php?act=ore', {cid : 1}, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i,el){
            var row = ($.tmpl( "tableRowTemplate", el);
            if(!result)
                result = row;
            else
                result.add(row);
        });
    });
    // do what you want to do with result
}
```